# Dependency injection with multiple inheritences when implementation does not matter

Tags: c#, dart, dependency-injection

I have a common question about architectural design and dependency injection. Because this fits in any programming language, I marked it with dart and c#, because both are similar and I know both.

I have an abstract class called **Base**. Two other classes are inheriting this **Base** class, which are called **Impl1** and **Impl2**. The base class defines a method called **doSomethingCommon()** that does something. The logic this method does is independent of the **Base** classes implementation, so **Impl1** and **Impl2** don't override this method.

```dart
abstract class Base {
  void doSomethingCommon(){
    print('TEST');
  }
}

class Impl1 extends Base {

}

class Impl2 extends Base {

}
```

Now in any other part of my program I need to run the method **doSomethingCommon()**, and because I am using Constructor Injection, I could inject **Impl1** or **Impl2** and run the method. But this seems not that clever for me, because this looks like that the mentioned code is coupled to that specific implementation of **Base**.

So I could inject the abstract class **Base** "itself", so I don't know the inherited type of "Base" which looks more as a good solution.

The problem with the second way is, that I need to define what is injected:

```dart
@injectable
AnyClass blaFoo(
  Impl1 impl1,
) =>
    AnyClass(
      impl1,
    );

class AnyClass {
  final Base _base;

  AnyClass(this._base){
    _base.doSomethingCommon();
  }
}
```

As you can see, when I define how **AnyClass** is beeing creatd for DI, I need to explicitly define what implementation of **Base** **AnyClass** will receive.

Is there a good practice how to achieve a good architectural design with this problem?
I hope I described my problem good enough, else please ask for clarity

Comment: I don't know enough about Dart to understand exactly what `AnyClass` is doing. It looks like you are calling the method in the constructor immediately after it is injected, which smells funny.

Comment: Sure, I just wrote down an example easy to understand, in real life I would not do it

Comment: Is your function `doSomethingCommon` based on a type? Then i'd reccomend writing an extension method.

Comment: It is based on different services and classes, so there is no way I could define the method as an extension. It must be defined inside the **Base** class

Comment: if `doSomethingCommon` is really independent of `Impl1` and `Impl2`, maybe it should be in a class by itself, instead of being in an abstract class. Then you can inject that class into `Impl1`, `Impl2` and `AnyClass`.

Comment: I completely agree with @kalleguld. Placing a function in Base it shouldn't be able to be used outside of it's implementations like `Impl1` or `Impl2`. Simply extract that function to its own Service

Answer (score 0):

Typically you'd control it by registering the `Base` class in your DI framework, like so:

```
IServiceCollection services;
services.AddTransient<Base, Impl1>();
```

Then when you request an instance of `Base` you get an `Impl1`.

```
class AnyClass{
    public AnyClass(Base base){
        //base will be Impl1 here
    }
}
```

Some, but not all, DI frameworks support a way of describing when to use `Impl1` and when to use `Impl2`. In [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/) you can do the following:

```
Bind<Base>().To<Impl2>().WhenInjectedInto<AnyClass>();
```

Comment: Defining which implementation will be injected seems also the best solution for me so far. But this still will result in defining, which will be used, which for an other developer will look like Impl1 is needed to be injected. So best would be that there is no need to define what implementation will be injected, but this seems not possible I think

Comment: What's the alternative? If you don't define it, who should? Should the DI container select a random implementation every time?

Comment: I am asking you what the alternative could be :'D Sure its not good if it chooses at random. I think the best solution is to comment that it is not relevant what implementation is used, as long as it extends **Base**.